# problem with filter of custom portfolio categories

Tags: categories, customization

I have created a custom portfolio with the following code in the function.php in a custom template.

```
if ( ! function_exists('custom_post_type_portafolio') ) {

// Register Custom Post Type
 function custom_post_type_portafolio() {

$labels = array(
 'name' => _x( 'Proyectos', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
 'singular_name' => _x( 'Proyecto', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
 'menu_name' => __( 'Portafolio', 'text_domain' ),
 'name_admin_bar' => __( 'Portafolio', 'text_domain' ),
 'archives' => __( 'Portafolio', 'text_domain' ),
 'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Proyecto superior', 'text_domain' ),
 'all_items' => __( 'Todos los proyectos', 'text_domain' ),
 'add_new_item' => __( 'Añadir nuevo proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
 'add_new' => __( 'Añadir nuevo Proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
 'new_item' => __( 'Nuevo proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
 'edit_item' => __( 'Editar proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
 'update_item' => __( 'Actualizar proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
 'view_item' => __( 'Ver proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
 'search_items' => __( 'Buscar proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
 'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
 'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
 'featured_image' => __( 'Imagen destacada', 'text_domain' ),
 'set_featured_image' => __( 'Añadir imagen destacada', 'text_domain' ),
 'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Quitar Imagen destacada', 'text_domain' ),
 'use_featured_image' => __( 'Usar como Imagen destacada', 'text_domain' ),
 'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
 'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
 'items_list' => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
 'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
 'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
 );
 $args = array(
 'label' => __( 'Proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
 'description' => __( 'Portafolio', 'text_domain' ),
 'labels' => $labels,
 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats', ),
 'taxonomies' => array( 'Portafolio-category', 'post_tag' ),
 'hierarchical' => true,
 'public' => true,
 'show_ui' => true,
 'show_in_menu' => true,
 'menu_position' => 5,
 'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
 'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
 'can_export' => true,
 'has_archive' => true,
 'exclude_from_search' => false,
 'publicly_queryable' => true,
 'capability_type' => 'page',
 );
 register_post_type( 'portafolio', $args );

}
 add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_portafolio', 0 );

}


if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_taxonomy_portafolio' ) ) {

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy_portafolio() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Tipos de proyectos', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Tipo Proyecto', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Tipos de proyectos', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'Todos los tipos de proyectos', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Tipo superior', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Tipo superior:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'Nuevo Tipo de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Añadir Nuevo Tipo de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Editar Tipo de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Actualizar Tipo de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'Ver Tipo de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separar tipos con comas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Añadir o quitar Nuevo Tipos de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Elegir entre los más usados', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Tipos de proyecto populares', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Buscar Tipos de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'No se encuentra', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No hay Tipos de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Lista de Tipos de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Navegación Tipos de proyecto', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'tipo_proyecto', array( 'portafolio' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_portafolio', 0 );

}
```

Print the posts correctly, do the loop of the categories for the menu well, on my portfolio.php page of my theme.
but I can not filter the projects by categories with the following code in archives.php.

```
 <div class="ai_section_2_2_proyectos">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled listado_proyectos">
                            <?php
                            $args=array(
                                'post_type' => 'Portafolio',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'orderby' => 'ASC',
                                'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                                'taxonomies' => array( 'tipo_proyecto', 'ecommerce' ),
                            );
                            // The Query
                            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            // The Loop
                            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                                    $the_query->the_post();
                                    ?>
                                    <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>" class="a_hover" data-image="<?=get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full')?>">
                                            <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline post-categories">
                                                <?
                                                $category = get_the_category();
                                                foreach( $category as $cat )
                                                {
                                                    echo "<li class='categories_li'>".$cat->name."</li>";
                                                    if ($cat === end($category)) {
                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                        echo "<li class='categories_li'>/</li>";
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                                <li class="ver_proyecto">Ver proyecto</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php }} else {
                                echo 'No hay artículos';
                                // no se encontraron artículos
                            }
                            /* Restore original Post Data */
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

I think the problem is in this part:

```
                    $args=array(
                        'post_type' => 'Portafolio',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'orderby' => 'ASC',
                        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                        'taxonomies' => $cat,
                    );
                    // The Query
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Hello, not sure it change something, but your post type is "portafolio" & you query "Portafolio" with a CAPS on the P.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the `taxonomies` param is correct.

To use taxonomies in  `WP_Query` args, they need to be wrapped in an array, and passed in via the `tax_query` param

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

But this code works in the categories filter of the post:

```
$args=array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'orderby' => 'ASC',
                                    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                                    'category__in' => $cat,
                                );
                                // The Query
                                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Why does not this work with the portfolios?

I have worked with this other solution but it does not work.

```
                    $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'portafolio',
            'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'tipo_proyecto',
                                        'field'    => 'slug',
                                        'terms'    => $cat,
                                    ),
                                ),
                    );
                    // The Query
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```